# Retrieving PostGIS selected table in PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, data-source

I would like to use the layer selected into the explorer's windows.

My aim is to launch script using the name of the PostGIS layer selecter in this windows.

[image]

Is it possible to retrieve the table selected in this windows?

The result I'm looking for is :

```
"astk2"."point_topo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find below a sample to illustrate how to do it. In fact, it's mostly a PyQt question as except a call to `iface.mainWindow()`, we relies only on Qt `QTreeView` methods

```py
panelNameInYourLang = 'Browser'
browser = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, panelNameInYourLang)

browserTreeView = browser.findChild(QTreeView)
selectionModel = browserTreeView.selectionModel()
browserModel = browserTreeView.model()

def selected(el):
    for i in el.indexes():
        if i.parent() and i.parent().parent() and i.parent().parent().parent() and i.parent().parent().parent().data() == 'PostGIS':
            print(f'{i.parent().data()}.{i.data()}')

selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(selected)
```